# Boxed equations and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, boxes, arrows

I would like to implement this 
into an align-environment (or equivalent) how can I do this? I tried with boxes but the structure is rather complicated since I want a large box on the left-hand side....

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I could not replicate the font other than using a Sans Serif family (it appears bold in mine).

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}


\tikzset{
    every node/.style={draw=gray, rounded corners, text centered,text width=3cm},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=latex,
        font=\sffamily
      ]
    \node[minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] (big) at (0,0) {text\\more text};

    \node[font=\Large\sffamily, right=of big.north east, anchor=north west,minimum height=1cm] (s1) {equation}; 
    \node[right=of big.south east, anchor=south west,minimum height=1cm] (s2) {a lot of text\\and another line};

    \node[draw=none] at ($(big.north east)!.5!(s1.south west)$) {$\times$};
    \node[draw=none] at ($(big.south east)!.5!(s2.north west)$) {$\times$};

    \draw[<->, shorten >=5mm, shorten <=5mm] (s1.south) -- (s2.north);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `X`, may be `$\times$`?

Comment: @Manuel Although in the question there are 2 Xs, that looks better (and probably the OP meant that symbol anyway). I'll change it.